# Installation Failed during intall_github with wilcox_R package

Tags: r, github

I am trying to use the `zdepth` R function from the package `wilcox_R` available at github. As suggested, I used the usual command lines:

> `library("devtools"); install_github("musto101/wilcox_R")`

However, I received the following error:

[image]

Any way out of this would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with the package metadata that are preventing it from building, probably because the author hasn't finished developing the package yet.

Probably the easiest way to use the `zdepth` function is to download the repository source code. Open the repository in github (https://github.com/musto101/wilcox_R) then click `Clone or Download` and `Download Zip`.

[image: Download Zip from Github]

Unzip the archive and the `zdepth` function looks like it's in `R/zdepth.R`. Copy this file to your own project then load the function with `source()`, e.g.: `source("R/zdepth.R")`.

This is not the 'best' way to use this function, particularly if you want to use other functions in the package, but short of fixing the metadata yourself it's the most straightforward.

Comment: package author didn't provide `title` info to the package helpful.  (https://github.com/musto101/wilcox_R/blob/master/man/Aband.Rd) which R cannot compile help page for users.